# Civicase- order results in find case

Tags: civicase, search

Following links in Civicase dashboard (4.6.38) normally takes you through to a set of search results in the Find Cases search.

Initially cases are displayed by client name, alphabetically.

There are options to order by most recent activity date, or next scheduled activity date. When used neither of these display as expected. Results list neother in activity type order, or date order.

On closer inspection using the sort arrows by either options sorts the results in case id order.

Just checked and this behaviour is the same in sandbox.

1) Is this a known bug? If not which project should I post it in in the new tracker pages?

2) Anyone got any workarounds?fixes for this?

Cheers

Craig

Comment: If you can replicate this behavior on https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/, you can proceed in creating an issue at https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/new

Comment: Thanks @jitendra-fuzion

I worked that out earlier today. The instructions on this page
https://civicrm.org/bug-reporting (point 7)

Links to the all projects page, rather than straight to the dev/ core project, which confused me on my first visit there. Because the follow up instructions didn't match with what I saw in gitlab.

Answer (score 1):

I think this issue may explain what's causing the issue in how it's ordering (or not ordering) https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17708

Not a solution but maybe a little further understanding.